# Which Maupassant short stories are set during the Franco-Prussian War of 1870?

Tags: identification-request, short-stories, french-language, guy-de-maupassant

I read somewhere that Maupassant wrote ten short stories on the 1870 war between France and Prussia. I know "Boule de suif", "Deux amis", "Un duel", "Madame Sauvage" and "Mademoiselle Fifi".

What are the five other stories?

Comment: Are you sure that all of the latter ten were truly by Maupassant? There's a number of short stories which have been [falsely attributed](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14259/17) to him, including at least one ("The Lancer’s Wife" / "La Uhlane" by Richepin) set during the Franco-Prussian war.

Comment: Hi Bazin. I don't understand why you deleted this question. You could have received answers to both questions if you had split them up as two separate posts. Before you deleted it, it had two reopen votes.

Comment: I've cast the final votes to undelete and reopen your question, now that it's been restricted to a single query, and I see you've posted the second one as a [new question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18321/17). Now hopefully you can get answers to both :-) (cc @Tsundoku)

Answer (score 4):

Besides the stories mentioned in the question, I have found the following stories by Maupassant that are set during the Franco-Prussian war:

- [Le Mariage du lieutenant Laré](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Mariage_du_lieutenant_Lar%C3%A9), published in 1878; see ["Le Mariage du lieutenant Laré" on Wikisource](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Boule_de_Suif_-_Correspondance/Le_Mariage_du_lieutenant_Lar%C3%A9),
- [La Folle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Folle), published in 1882; see ["La Folle" on Wikisource](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Contes_de_la_b%C3%A9casse_(Havard,_1894)/La_Folle),
- [L'Aventure de Walter Schnaffs](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Aventure_de_Walter_Schnaffs), published in 1883; see ["L’Aventure de Walter Schnaffs" on Wikisource](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Contes_de_la_b%C3%A9casse_(Havard,_1894)/L%E2%80%99Aventure_de_Walter_Schnaffs),
- [Le Père Milon](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_P%C3%A8re_Milon), published in 1883; see ["Le Père Milon" on Wikisource](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Le_P%C3%A8re_Milon_(recueil)/Le_P%C3%A8re_Milon),
- [Saint-Antoine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Antoine_(Maupassant)), published in 1883; see ["Saint-Antoine" on Wikisource](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Contes_de_la_b%C3%A9casse_(Havard,_1894)/Saint-Antoine),
- [Les Rois](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Rois), published in 1887; see ["Les Rois" on Wikisource](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Le_Horla_(recueil,_Ollendorff_1895)/Les_Rois).

It appears that Maupassant wrote **eleven short stories that are set during the Franco-Prussian war**, unless I overlooked one (or more).